# Imaging a corrupted NTFS

Tags: ntfs, forensics, disk-image

I have an ext. drive with a corrupted NTFS (in the sense that NTFS-3G refuses to mount it).

I really want to just take an image of the drive, stash that somewhere for later, and reformat the drive so I can use it normally. I don't want to lose any of my files on the drive.

Question: Is there a way to take an (compressed?) image of the drive that will preserve it bit-for-bit and allow me to do forensics later?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179

Answer (score 1):

Just copying the device someplace should work:

```
dd if=/dev/whatever of=/some/file/to/save
```

The default blocksize (`bs=...`) flag should be fine, in any case setting it wrong will at most make it slow down.

If the filesystem might be broken due to hardware problems, experiment with other filesystems first, and make sure the `bs` is a multiple of the hardware block size. When disks start behaving erratically, they *usually* have at most hours of life left in them.

Comment: What about compressing the dump?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `raw` to bind the partition's block device to a raw character device and then use `dd` to read the partition image. Make sure that `bs` is the actual sector size of the disk, or some multiple thereof. (The default should work, I believe.)